WorkStep object: How to retrieve Status field picklist options with Status Category values
We are trying to retrive via sf cli metadata for WorkStep.Status picklist field:

The challenge is that Status Category values are not coming back with retrieved metadata.
Below is the snippet of metadata that is returned by sf cli when retrieving with option like -m "StandardValueSet:WorkStepStatus"
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<StandardValueSet xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <sorted>false</sorted>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>New</fullName>
        <default>true</default>
        <label>New</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Completed</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Completed</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Not Applicable</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Not Applicable</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Cannot Complete</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Cannot Complete</label>
    </standardValue>
    <standardValue>
        <fullName>Test Label</fullName>
        <default>false</default>
        <label>Test Label</label>
    </standardValue>
</StandardValueSet>

Are we doing something wrong? If it is not retrieved via metadata, how to manage then Status Categories at git repo level to make repo a real source of truth?
Any help or advice would be appreciated re how we can achieve this, maybe with some alternative ways that can be automated (if no chances with metadata). Cause, as of now it seems like we can get/set category only via web UI.
